# Как заполнить пропуски в столбце на основании данных из нескольких других столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Мне необходимо заполнить пропуски в столбце birth_date значениями, которые уже известны для именно этих пользователей (на основании группировки по f_name, s_name и tel). Точно известно, что такие комбинации уникальны.

Возможно ли это сделать? Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Иван', 'Иванов', '1', '01/01/2001'],
                   ['Иван', 'Петров', '2', '02/02/2002'],
                   ['Иван', 'Иванов', '3', '03/03/2003'],
                   ['Иван', 'Иванов', '2', '04/04/2004'],
                   ['Иван', 'Петров', '1', '05/05/2005'],
                   ['Иван', 'Иванов', '3', np.nan],
                   ['Иван', 'Петров', '1', np.nan]], columns=['f_name', 's_name', 'tel', 'birth_date'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать группировкой с заполнением:

```
df["birth_date"] = df.groupby(["f_name", "s_name", "tel"])["birth_date"].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().fillna(method="ffill"))
```

df:

```
  f_name  s_name tel  birth_date
0   Иван  Иванов   1  01/01/2001
1   Иван  Петров   2  02/02/2002
2   Иван  Иванов   3  03/03/2003
3   Иван  Иванов   2  04/04/2004
4   Иван  Петров   1  05/05/2005
5   Иван  Иванов   3  03/03/2003
6   Иван  Петров   1  05/05/2005
```

**UPDATE**

если у вас возникает ошибка incompatible index, то это происходит из-за того, что в процессе группировки у вас появляется мультииндекс

Можно попробовать исправить так:

```
res = df.groupby(["f_name", "s_name", "tel"]).apply(lambda x: x["birth_date"].
                                                    sort_values().fillna(method="ffill")).reset_index().sort_values("level_3").drop(columns=["level_3"])
```

res:

```
  f_name  s_name tel  birth_date
0   Иван  Иванов   1  01/01/2001
6   Иван  Петров   2  02/02/2002
2   Иван  Иванов   3  03/03/2003
1   Иван  Иванов   2  04/04/2004
4   Иван  Петров   1  05/05/2005
3   Иван  Иванов   3  03/03/2003
5   Иван  Петров   1  05/05/2005
​
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, только при больших данных этот код вываливается вот с такой ошибкой, incompatible index of inserted column with frame index. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: ну тяжело лечить по фотографии. возможно в вашей реальной таблице появляется мультииндекс где-то. или вы группировку делаете с as_index=False.

Comment: не-не, в моей большой табличке нет никаких мультииндексов, но кроме этих столбцов, которые я указала в примере, есть еще десяток других столбцов. Этот код работает только для такой размерности, верно я поняла?

Comment: мультииндекс у вас появляется при группировке, поскольку группируете вы по трем колонкам.

Comment: Теперь я поняла, почему ошибка, спасибо огромное. А не могли бы Вы мне подсказать, как мне быть с этой же задачей, если у меня есть еще куча столбцов, в которых я хочу оставить всё как есть, только добавить birth_date с группировкой только по 3 из 10 столбцов? Или это нереально сделать?

Comment: я обновил ответ. попробуйте новое решение

Comment: Не знаю, как Вас благодарить!!!

Comment: Благодарить здесь принято принятием ответа, если он вам помог.